# Adding .html to end of page url?

Tags: entries, url

I am currently using Craft to manage only certain pages on a site. The static pages all end in `.html` but Craft's pages don't. Is there a way to rewrite them via Craft to add `.html` or do I have to do some `.htaccess` wizardry? I only want to rewrite the pages and not the categories (for example, /news/).

If I can achieve this, should I? Are there enough SEO benefits to a consistent URL format? I've also read using `.htaccess` in this way may affect SEO negatively, which is why I'm wondering if there's a way of doing it with Craft.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your entry's URL format right inside Craft. It's under Settings -> Sections then choose the section you want.

[image]

Under URL Format, just add `.html` after the `{slug}`. In this example, I've also added the year that the entry was added to the URL as well and you can really make it whatever you want.

Using `.htaccesss` you could also [remove the `.html`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730092/how-to-remove-html-from-url) extension from the static pages too if you want to follow Craft's format (though be careful with that one).

## SEO

As far as whether it's a good idea to do either for SEO purposes, you're going to get a lot of differing opinions. I'm a URL minimalist,  so I tend to keep my URLs simple, including removing `www` from the hostname and removing any trailing slash from URLs if possible.

Google tends to favor [short URLs](http://backlinko.com/search-engine-ranking) among other things but it's not a big factor.

Content is content. Years ago, I remember there used to be some SEO benefit to adding `.html` but if search engines can index it, it doesn't matter what the URL is.

The bigger issue for me is any time you change a URL, you risk blowing something up. I'm always reminded of the saying [Cool URLs don't change](http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html).

If your site has been around awhile,  I wouldn't mess with them. Other people may be linking to your pages and if you change the URLs, you'll want to put in 301 redirects—otherwise they'll 404, which is a much bigger problem.